# Brackets around indices change their size

Tags: fontsize, subscripts

My expression is

```
\nabla^{(0)}_{\left(a\right|}\nabla^{(0)}_{c}\bar{h}_{\left|b\right)}^c
```

which produces on my machine

[image: A lot of indexing]

Clearly the indices with brackets around are larger than the non-bracketed ones. I would like all of them to have the same size. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: `\left` and `\right` only do evil in those places.

Comment: @egreg But with the name "Thunder`\Bigg`i", he is already on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\vphantom`s for the lone scripts, so as to give them the same vertical footprint as a paren.  Also, in a case like this, the `\left...\right` additions are not helpful and just throw confusion on the syntax.  I have removed them.

Per egreg's suggestion, the use of `|` was replaced with the `\rvert` and `\lvert`, respectively, from the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\nabla^{(0)}_{(a\rvert}\nabla^{(0)}_{
  \vphantom{(} c}\bar{h}_{\lvert b)}^{\vphantom{)} c}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the `\vphantom` basically makes the bracket invisible?

Comment: @ThunderBiggi A `\phantom` would place its [full-width] argument invisibly (i.e., reserve a vertical *and* horizontal space), whereas a `\vphantom` places a zero-width but full-height version of the invisible argument (reserves *only* a vertical space).

Comment: It should be `\rvert` in the first subscript and `\lvert` in the second one (needs `amsmath`).

Comment: @egreg I didn't know about them - they seem to be slightly smaller - neat!